# Let $a(s)$: curve with non-zero curvature. Prove that $a(s)$ lies on a plane iff there is a point x such that all osculating plane passes through $x$.

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm trying to prove if plane lies on a plane, then there is a fixed point such that all osculating planes goes through this point.

I've seen answers saying differentiate $\alpha(s)=a(s)T(s)+b(s)N(s)$ and apply Frenet.

then the Equation becomes:
\begin{align}
\alpha'(s)&=a'(s)T(s)+a(s)T'(s)+b'(s)N(s)+b(s)N'(s)\\
\alpha'(s)&=a'(s)T(s)+a(s)kN(s)+b'(s)N(s)+b(s)(-kT+tB)
\end{align}
but I can't figure out how to proceed from here. how to you get that tao goes to 0 from this equation?

also the question is if and only if so I need to prove the other way but all the answers only prove one way.

How should I prove if all osculating plane goes through a fixed point, then the curvature lies on a plane?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The osculating plane can be defined by the equation $\langle B,x\rangle=0$.

Let's assume the existence of some (constant) $p\in\mathbb R^3$ such that $\langle B,p\rangle\equiv0$. Since $p=0$ is a trivial solution for this, I'll also assume that $p\ne0$.

Taking the derivative we obtain $\langle B',p\rangle\equiv0$. Since $B'=\tau N$, we get $\tau\langle N,p\rangle\equiv0$.

**Claim:** $\tau\equiv0$. Suppose toward a contradiction that $\tau(s_0)\ne0$ for some $s_0$. Then $\langle N(s_0),p\rangle=0$. Taking derivatives,
$$
  \tau\langle N',p\rangle
    = \tau'\langle N,p\rangle + \tau\langle N',p\rangle
    = 0\quad(\textrm{at }s_0)
$$
i.e.,
$$
   \langle N',p\rangle = 0\quad(\textrm{at }s_0)
$$
Substitute $N' = -kT-\tau B$ and get
$$
  k\langle T,p\rangle = k\langle T,p\rangle
                +\tau\langle B,p\rangle
                = 0\quad(\textrm{at }s_0)
$$
Since $k\ne0$, it must be $\langle T(s_0),p\rangle$. Since $\langle N(s_0),p\rangle=0$ and $\langle B,p\rangle=0$ and $\{T, N, B\}$ is an orthonomal basis of $\mathbb R^3$, we get $p=0$; a contradiction. Then $\tau\equiv0$ as claimed.

Now we can use the result that says $\tau\equiv0\iff$im$(\alpha)$ is included in a plane. Since we are only interested here in the $\Rightarrow$ part, I'll recall how to prove it. Without loss of generality we will assume $\alpha(c)=0$ for some $c$ in the domain of $\alpha$.

First observe that $\tau\equiv0\implies B$ constant. Let $H$ be the osculating plane common to all points. As we saw above, $H$ is defined by the equation $\langle B,x\rangle=0$. Since $\langle B,T\rangle\equiv0$, the map $s\mapsto\langle B,\alpha\rangle$ is constant. And since it evaluates to $0$ at $c$,
$$
       \langle B,\alpha\rangle\equiv0,
$$
i.e., $\alpha(s)\in H$ for all $s$.

Comment: τ⟨N′,p⟩=τ′⟨N,p⟩+τ⟨N′,p⟩=0 could you explain how do you get this equation? Did you differentiate τ⟨N,p⟩? then isn't the equation suppose to be τ⟨N',p⟩+τ⟨N,p'⟩ since τ is constant? since p is constant p' is 0 and we still get the same conclusion but I just want to make sure

Comment: Yes, I did differentiate $\tau\langle N,p\rangle$ and then evaluated at $s_0$. To get this derivative first apply the derivative of the product $\tau'\langle N,p\rangle + \tau\langle N,p\rangle'$ and then observe that $\langle N,p\rangle'=\langle N',p\rangle + \langle N,p'\rangle>$, where the last term vanishes because $p$ is constant and therefore $p'=0$.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I'm really confused on the last sentence: ⟨B,x⟩=0. Since ⟨B,T⟩≡0, the map s↦⟨B,α⟩ is constant. I get that ⟨B,T⟩=0 because it is orthornomal, but how does that lead to the map s↦⟨B,α⟩ is constant? I thought B must pe perp to α since α is on a plane, but it saids ⟨B,α⟩ is constant. So I'm confused

Comment: Also even if B is not constant, doesn't ⟨B,α⟩≡0 at c since α(c)=0? Why do we need the condition B is constant to conclude that  α(s)∈H? I understand that if  ⟨B,α⟩≡0 then α(s)∈H by the definition of osculating plane.

Comment: Notice that $B'=\tau N$. Therefore, $\tau=0\implies B'=0\implies B$ constant. In particular, $s\mapsto\langle B,\alpha(s)\rangle$ is constant because its derivative is $\langle B,\alpha'(s)\rangle=0$ since $B\perp T$.